same uid anonymous writing to firebase from different browsers. What's going on?
I am writing to firebase, using     "@angular/fire": "^18.0.1",. And it is the only firebase package in my .json file.
I wait for UID. I only console log one uid.
private auth: Auth = inject(Auth);
  user: Observable<any> | undefined;
  uid!: string;

  async ngOnInit() {
    this.user = authState(this.auth);
    try {
      const userObject = await signInAnonymously(getAuth());
      this.uid = userObject.user.uid;
      console.log(this.uid);

    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Authentication error:", error);
    }
  }

  async waitForUid() {
    while (!this.uid) {
      await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 10));
    }
  }

Then I write to firebase:
async ngOnInit() {
    await this.appComponent.waitForUid().then(() => {
      this.uid = this.appComponent.uid;
      this.loadCurrentListName();
    });

  }

  loadCurrentListName() {
    const listRef = ref(this.db, 'users/' + this.appComponent.uid + '/currentList/');
    get(listRef).then((snapshot) => {
      if (snapshot.exists()) {
        this.currentListName.set(snapshot.val());
      } else {
        const newPushRef = push(listRef);
        set(newPushRef, '');
        this.currentListName.set(newPushRef.key ?? '');
      }
    });
  }

Here's the weird part. It writes to firebase with two UIDs.
{
  "users": {
    "y7S1zoK2ccQHZlNMlAiNI2mlxHz2": {
      "currentList": "-O2kxqekEiDi8npAUAWj"
    },
    "ypG9okgfYkOqjznl2Q4yionRj3M2": {
      "currentList": "-O2kxrE9EVM1E2RBiu05"
    }
  }
}


It get's weirder. I change browsers. Firefox and chrome. New UID that I can console log. But I also get:
m7pX5r2aVyeNiDC1LKrjcV9VjZS2 in all of them. Same in incognito.
Anyone have a clue wtf is going on?
I only expected to write with the UID I can console log out. The m7pX5r2aVyeNiDC1LKrjcV9VjZS2  that seems to inject itself into all browsers, is strange. Really strange. Like some global uid is jumping in.
Can it be a login from another project not open? Like if I logged in to another project?
It also happens in firefox without any extensions.

Can you replace the schematic representation of the data with the actual JSON from the database (as text, no screenshots please)? You can export this from the Firebase console and then add it to your question.

I tried logging out. That changes the uid of both. But one is persistent between browsers. Just a new persistent UID

Hmm... nothing in the code you shared would explain the two UIDs in that JSON. You might want to add some logging and see if signInAnonymously is being called multiple times, and what UID you get back from that.

Would this kind of logging suffice?
ngOnInit() {
this.auth.onAuthStateChanged(async (user) => {
if (user) {
this.uid = user.uid;
console.log("this.uid1", this.uid);
} else {
try {
const userObject = await signInAnonymously(getAuth());
this.uid = userObject.user.uid;
console.log("this.uid2", this.uid);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Authentication error:", error);
    }
  }
});

}
And if so, it's not called after the first time giving a uid.

I'm maybe more stumped by the UID carrying over into other browsers and incognito. Is there anything I can do to help figure out what is causing it?

@FrankvanPuffelen should UID be moving between browsers. Searching here in Stackoverflow it looks like it shouldn't right? I'll gladly share my project with you, if it helps, or whatever assistant that can be useful.
